# event mouseclicked in java not working to populate text field

Tags: java, swing

I am making a gui with netbeans. I right clicked a `JTable` to add event listener for mouse clicked. I added my code to the new method. For the life of me when I click the `JTable` I get no errors.
Any ideas on what I am doing wrong or how to fix it? if you need to see more of my code let me know. everything besides the connection to the DB is ran out of the driver class.

I moved my program to eclipse to make this easier for me to trouble shoot.

```
    private void tableDisplayMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                          

   try {
       int row = tableDisplay.getSelectedRow();
       String tableClick = (tableDisplay.getModel().getValueAt(row, 1).toString());
       String sql = " select * from contact where id = ' " + tableClick + " ' ";
       pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
   rs = pst.executeQuery();
       if(rs.next()) {
            System.out.println("hey dude this method is being called.");   
           String add2 = rs.getString("Business_Name");
           fieldBN.setText(add2);   
           String add3 = rs.getString("First_Name");
           fieldFN.setText(add3);   
           String add4 = rs.getString("Last_Name");
           fieldLN.setText(add4);   
           String add5 = rs.getString("Phone");
           fieldP.setText(add5);   
           String add6 = rs.getString("Email");
           fieldE.setText(add6);   
           String add7 = rs.getString("Address_Line_1");
           fieldA.setText(add7);   
           String add8 = rs.getString("Address_Line_2");
           aLine2.setText(add8);   
           String add9 = rs.getString("Website");
           fieldW.setText(add9);                     
       }
   }
  catch(Exception e) {
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
  }
}
```

Here is the onclick method

Here is my even listener

```
public Driver() {       
    gui();      
    conn = DbConnect.ConnectDb();
    UpdateTable();

       tableDisplay.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
            public void mouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
                tableDisplayMouseClicked(evt);
            }
        });
}
```

Here is the whole Driver Class:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;

public class Driver {

    private JFrame f;

    private JPanel p;

    private JTextField fieldBN;
    private JTextField fieldFN;
    private JTextField fieldLN;
    private JTextField fieldP;
    private JTextField fieldE;
    private JTextField fieldA;
    private JTextField aLine2;
    private JTextField fieldW;

    private JLabel labelBN;
    private JLabel labelFN;
    private JLabel labelLN;
    private JLabel labelP;
    private JLabel labelE;
    private JLabel labelA;
    private JLabel labelW;

    private JComboBox relationship;

    private JButton buttonS;

    private JTable tableDisplay;

    String[] relationshipValues = { "Business", "Friend", "Family", "Professional" };

    Connection conn = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    PreparedStatement pst = null;

    // Constructor:

    public Driver() {       
        gui();      
        conn = DbConnect.ConnectDb();
        UpdateTable();

           tableDisplay.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
                public void mouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
                    tableDisplayMouseClicked(evt);
                }
            });
    }

    public void gui() { 
        f = new JFrame("Contact Book");


        GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();  

        p = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        f.getContentPane().add(p, BorderLayout.NORTH);

    c.gridx = 0;
    c.gridy = 0;
    labelBN = new JLabel ("Business Name:");
    p.add(labelBN, c);  

    c.gridx = 1;
    c.gridy = 0;
    fieldBN = new JTextField(10);
    p.add(fieldBN, c);

    c.gridx = 0;
    c.gridy = 1;
    labelFN= new JLabel ("First Name:");
    p.add(labelFN, c);      

    c.gridx = 1;
    c.gridy = 1;
    fieldFN = new JTextField (10);
    p.add(fieldFN, c);

    c.gridx = 0;
    c.gridy = 2;
    labelLN= new JLabel ("Last Name:");
    p.add(labelLN, c);      

    c.gridx = 1;
    c.gridy = 2;
    fieldLN = new JTextField (10);
    p.add(fieldLN, c);

    c.gridx = 0;
    c.gridy = 3;
    labelP = new JLabel ("Phone Number:");
    p.add(labelP, c);

    c.gridx = 1;
    c.gridy = 3;
    fieldP = new JTextField (10);
    p.add(fieldP, c);

    c.gridx = 0;
    c.gridy = 4;
    labelE = new JLabel ("Email:");
    p.add(labelE, c);

    c.gridx = 1;
    c.gridy = 4;
    fieldE = new JTextField (10);
    p.add(fieldE, c);

    c.gridx = 0;
    c.gridy = 5;                            
    labelA = new JLabel ("Address:");
    p.add(labelA, c);

    c.gridx = 1;
    c.gridy = 5;
    fieldA = new JTextField (10);
    p.add(fieldA, c);
    c.gridx = 1;
    c.gridy = 6;
    aLine2 = new JTextField (10);
    p.add(aLine2, c);

    c.gridx = 0;
    c.gridy = 7;
    labelW = new JLabel ("Website:");
    p.add(labelW, c);

    c.gridx = 1;
    c.gridy = 7;
    fieldW = new JTextField (10);
    p.add(fieldW, c);

    c.gridx = 0;
    c.gridy = 8;
    labelW = new JLabel ("Relationship:");
    p.add(labelW, c);

    c.gridx = 1;
    c.gridy = 8;
    relationship = new JComboBox(relationshipValues);
    p.add(relationship, c);

    c.gridx = 1;
    c.gridy = 9;
    buttonS = new JButton("Save:");
    p.add(buttonS, c);

    c.gridx = 0;
    c.gridy = 10;
    tableDisplay = new JTable();
    p.add(tableDisplay, c);


        // pack the frame for better cross platform support
        f.pack();
        // Make it visible
        f.setVisible(true);
        f.setSize(1400,900); // default size is 0,0
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    } // End of Gui Method

    private void UpdateTable() {
        try {
        String sql = "SELECT * FROM contact";
        pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
        rs = pst.executeQuery();
        tableDisplay.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));
    }

    catch(Exception e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
    }
    }


    private void tableDisplayMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                          

   try {
       int row = tableDisplay.getSelectedRow();
       String tableClick = (tableDisplay.getModel().getValueAt(row, 1).toString());
       String sql = " select * from contact where id = ' " + tableClick + " ' ";
       pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
   rs = pst.executeQuery();
       if(rs.next()) {
            System.out.println("hey dude this method is being called.");   
           String add2 = rs.getString("Business_Name");
           fieldBN.setText(add2);   
           String add3 = rs.getString("First_Name");
           fieldFN.setText(add3);   
           String add4 = rs.getString("Last_Name");
           fieldLN.setText(add4);   
           String add5 = rs.getString("Phone");
           fieldP.setText(add5);   
           String add6 = rs.getString("Email");
           fieldE.setText(add6);   
           String add7 = rs.getString("Address_Line_1");
           fieldA.setText(add7);   
           String add8 = rs.getString("Address_Line_2");
           aLine2.setText(add8);   
           String add9 = rs.getString("Website");
           fieldW.setText(add9);                     
       }
   }
  catch(Exception e) {
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
  }
}    



    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
           public void run() {
                new Driver();

           }
        });
    } // End main Method

       } // End class Driver
```

Comment: Have you tried adding a `System.out.println(...)` into the code to check if the method is been called and or the `rs.next` block is been entered into?  How about setting a break point and debugging the method?

Comment: ok ya good call I systemoutprint and the method is not being called. I am terrible at java.. so I need to call the method now. so i just add tableDisplayMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) right?

Comment: No, it sounds like the event registration didn't work...

Comment: so delete it and do it again?

Comment: man i deleted everywhere it brought it up and not when i right click the Jtable and add it again nothing happens

Comment: You could be using multiple instance of `JTable`.  Do it manually [How to write Mouse Listeners](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/mouselistener.html)

Comment: Ok I think I did this manually... To make it easier I switched over to Eclipse and have the program working and running. The click function to populate the text fields from the Jtable which is populated by a database is still not working. I updated my question to make it easier to follow me here. its the click method the event listener then my full driver class. I appreciate your help.

Comment: You do realise that your query has spaces in it... `id = ' " + tableClick + " ' "` would equate to `id = ' somevalue '`

Comment: I am following a tutorial.. and this part of the screen is hard to see what the guy is doing..

Comment: I am in an intro to java class. I understand what the line is saying but I dont know enough about the syntax to know if its correct.

Comment: You are searching for a value in the database, but you're adding a space before and after the value you are looking for.  Unless the values in your database match this EXACT value, the query will fail

Comment: so your saying there should be no spacees everywhere between the ' '?

Comment: No "extra" spaces...it should look more like `id = '" + tableClick + "'`

Comment: gotcha it works. everywhere between ' ' man your great. Thanks. I cant wait to no more about this is killing me

Comment: submit your answer please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's difficult to know why you're having issues with the registering a `MouseListener`, there's not enough context to diagnose the problem.

You should start by placing out put statements in the code to check to see if the method is been called and that the query is returning values.

If all else fails, you should try regsitering the mouse listener manually.  See [How to Write a Mouse Listener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/mouselistener.html) for more details.

You query is also including spaces in the match...

```
String sql = " select * from contact where id = ' " + tableClick + " ' ";
                                                 ^------------------^-----
```

Which will affect the ability for the database to match results to your query.  Try removing these

```
String sql = " select * from contact where id = '" + tableClick + "'";
```